# Метод не видит других переменных и другие методы класса

Tags: c++

Перегруженный метод не видит другие методы класса и публичные члены. Из-за чего может такое случиться?

```
    public:

        void End_Race();

        void Draw_Data(int);

        bool Get_Sum(Player*);

        bool Get_Bet(int);

        bool Get_Bet(int, Player*);

        void Menu_Script();

        bool New_Game();

        SDL_Surface* New_Frame();

        bool OnInit();

        void OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event);

        void OnLoop();

        void OnRender();

        void OnCleanup();
};
```

Метод **Get_Bet(int)** работает прекрасно, но метод **Get_Bet(int, Player*)** не работает.

```
bool Get_Bet(int pers, Player* player){
    SDL_Surface *menu_surf;
    menu *new_bet_menu;
    bool check=false;
    new_bet_menu = new menu;
    menu_surf=(*new_bet_menu).Get_Bet(pers);
    SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
    bool menu_bet_doing =true;
    while(menu_bet_doing){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)) {
            switch(Event.type){  
                case SDL_KEYDOWN: 
                    switch(Event.key.keysym.sym){
                        case SDLK_UP:
                            if((*new_bet_menu).menu_step>1){
                                (*new_bet_menu).menu_step--;
                                menu_surf=(*new_bet_menu).Get_Bet(pers);
                                SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                            }
                            break;
                        case SDLK_DOWN:
                            if((*new_bet_menu).menu_step<5){
                                (*new_bet_menu).menu_step++;
                                menu_surf=(*new_bet_menu).Get_Bet(pers);
                                SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                            }
                            break;
                        case SDLK_RETURN:
                            switch ((*new_bet_menu).menu_step){
                                case 1:
                                        (*player).tar=1;
                                     if(Get_Sum(player)==true){
                                        //if(i==count_players-1)return true;
                                        menu_bet_doing=false;
                                        //SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                                     };SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                        (*player).tar=2;

                                    if(Get_Sum(player)==true){
                                         //if(i==count_players-1)return true;
                                        menu_bet_doing=false;
                                        //SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                                     };SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                                     break;
                                case 3:
                                        (*player).tar=3;
                                     if(Get_Sum(player)==true){
                                         //if(i==count_players-1)return true;
                                        menu_bet_doing=false;
                                        //SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                                     };SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                                     break;
                                case 4:
                                        (*player).tar=4;
                                     if(Get_Sum(player)==true){
                                      //if(i==count_players-1)return true;
                                        menu_bet_doing=false;
                                        //SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                                     };SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                                    break;
                                case 5:
                                        (*player).tar=5;

                                     if(Get_Sum(player)==true){
                                        //if(i==count_players-1)return true;
                                        menu_bet_doing=false;
                                        //SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);
                                     };SDL_BlitSurface(menu_surf, NULL, Surf_Display, NULL);

                                     break;

                    }
            }
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Проблемы возникают с публичным полем **Surf_Display** и с методом **Get_Sum()**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно вы обьявили метод вне зоны действия namespace класса.

Comment: Покажите код ...

Comment: Приведите код. Вы не забыли указать public при наследовании?

Comment: Возможно у вас конфликт с колличеством `{` и `}`

Comment: Но дело в том, что если я даю абсолютно другое название этой функции, ошибка та же. Следовательно, дело не в перегрузке

Comment: А где имя класса перед именем метода? И где Surf_Display объявлен?

Comment: Да, дебил, вопрос закрыт

Comment: Ох, ну зачем кидать эти простыни кода. Почитайте, что такое [mcve] хотя бы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед именем метода нету имени класса::. То есть у вас - свободная функция. Вот она ничего и не видит, ибо к классу не имеет отношения.